# Do key commands exist to navigate up and down Final Cut Pro Timeline?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro

I Have a massive timeline (image below). I scroll above the fold (yes there are even more clips above these)....yet I need to go back to the primary story line and it is becoming VERY tedious to do so. Is there not a key command to bring the primary story line into view?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This article might help. 
[Select a clip with the keyboard](http://www.fcp.co/final-cut-pro/tutorials/1741-selecting-a-connected-clip-without-a-mouse-in-final-cut-pro-x)

Answer (score 0):

Would be super useful to 'select main stroyline' or some such, but the best I have found is:

Select the clip **under** the pointer in the timeline `c`

Select the clip **above** the current timeline selection at the skimmer or playhead location `⌘↑` (cmd + up-arrow)

Select the clip **below** the current timeline selection at the skimmer or playhead location `⌘↓` (cmd + down-arrow)

The other possibility is use `⇧⌘-` (Shift + Cmd + Hyphen) to decrease the clip size quickly to see more of the timeline, and increase with `⇧⌘=` (Shift + Cmd + Equals)